# heroku how to change the current app's git repo to a new one

Tags: heroku

So I deployed an app on heroku using github repo, it will get the code from this repo

```
https://github.com/name/cms2
```

It was successfully deployed. And worked well.

Now I want my heroku app to change the git repo to this repo

```
https://github.com/name/cms3
```

I no longer need the code in old repo. I want every future deploy, heroku will get the code form new repo. How can I do that ?

Comment: no it doesn't..

Comment: @angrykiwi, yes it does. I'll mark it a dupe tomorrow when I get more close votes.